# Swift and Google Maps SDK. Confused with Bridging Header

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode6

I am new to iOS development and trying to user the Google Maps SDK with Swift. According to the docs I have to do the following to import Objectiv-C libraries into a Swift project:

> Under Build Settings, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting under Swift Compiler - Code Generation has a path to the header. The path must be directly to the file itself, not the directory that it’s in.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html

The mentioned settings look like this: http://image.bayimg.com/f0674c9d6da65a0b8b2aada4ead273635625e83e.jpg

Where should I add the path to the header which I want to use?

Comment: Image shows you added the bridging header file properly. Now you an import the google SDK files to bridging header file as you do in ObjC

Comment: @Anil Thanks. I misunderstood the docs. I imported the header in my Swift class instead of the Bridging-Header.

Comment: Its best to use the bridge header to import non-swift compatible libraries..

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Problem solved thanks to Anil's comment. I misunderstood the docs. Xcode creates a Header-File named `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` in the project, and the ObjectiveC Libraries can be imported there. In my case it looks like this:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

> After that, functions from GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h can be accessed in every Swift class.